# FB.ui share, no response when shared from App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using FB.ui to allow users to share my pages with this code:

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName('sharefbbtn')[0].onclick = function() {    
    if(!burl){
        burl = window.location.href ;
    }  
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: burl
  }, function(response){
      if (response && !response.error_code) {
          //Thank the user
        } else{
          //Do nothing
        }

  });
}
```

When pages are shared from the imbedded browser in the android mobile app the user can choose which app to use to open the share dialog. If Facebook app is chosen, there is no callback response. In normal desktop browser everything works as expected.
Is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/) the response callback is not supported. Use "feed" instead, you will get a response call back and the dialog looks less intrusive.